Solr - connection timeout after moving to container
We migrated a Solr server to a Compute Engine Container, using the Solr docker image, still in standalone mode.  Same data, same Solr configs.  We are now seeing random connection timeouts (> 4 seconds) to the server when traffic picks up.  The container has more memory than the previous server and we're not seeing a spike in cpu or memory usage when this happens.
Logs are not helpful, the requests are not even making it to the Solr logs.
Is this an issue with Solr config?  Docker?  Is there a docker "Max connections" setting somewhere?
